# In support of Academia's moderator on hiatus, Eykanal

Tags: discussion

I encourage everyone at Academia to take a look at the proposed [Day of Silence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335627/287826) which some frustrated StackExchange participants will be observing for 24 hours, starting tonight at midnight (Eastern Standard time).  You may want to join this action (inaction) as a way of supporting Eykanal and other moderators who are similarly taking a break from moderating.

For additional information about what's going on, please see [Summing up the main issues (The Story So Far)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334399/287826).

Comment: Oops, I missed this post, and ended up not knowing about the day of silence until it had already passed.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni - same here!  I was offline most of last week, and I'm disappointed to see that things are unchanged pretty much (from what I can tell on meta.SE)

Comment: I've read several posts about this matter and I just cannot tell why anyone would care about it.  I can understand that pronouns are important to people, but this doesn't even seem to be about pronouns...   It seems like people are loosing sight of the big picture of Stack Exchange, which is that Stack Exchange is just a website.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni - Each Friday can be a silent expression of unhappiness with the state of affairs until things get unstuck.  Please note that I was at a conference and am just starting to get caught up reading what's been happening this week.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist - There are quite a few volunteer moderators who do care about what happened.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist It's not about pronouns: it's about about the firing of a moderator and the way that happened and was subsequently mishandled.